# Android Studio connecting to a URL

Tags: java, php, android, url, connection

My problem is that  I made a "web" with php to register, login and logout. What I really want to do is connect the web to my app in android studio, it worked before I put the page welcome in the website, but when I try to apply the changes, the app fails when I login.

The website:

```
http://saveds.esy.es/cas/login.php
```

The Android Studio code in java by directories:

JSONParser.java

```
package com.example.javi.myapplication2;

import android.util.Log;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}


public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(final String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // Construct the client and the HTTP request.
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        // Execute the POST request and store the response locally.
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        // Extract data from the response.
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        // Open an inputStream with the data content.
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        // Create a BufferedReader to parse through the inputStream.
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        // Declare a string builder to help with the parsing.
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        // Declare a string to store the JSON object data in string form.
        String line = null;
```

Login.java

```
package com.example.javi.myapplication2;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Login extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private EditText user, pass;
private Button mSubmit, mRegister;
private CheckBox check;


private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Clase JSONParser
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();


// si trabajan de manera local "localhost" :
// En windows tienen que ir, run CMD > ipconfig
// buscar su IP
// y poner de la siguiente manera
// "http://xxx.xxx.x.x:1234/cas/login.php";

private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://saveds.esy.es/cas/login.php";

// La respuesta del JSON es
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    // setup input fields
    user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    check = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.rememberme);

    // setup buttons
    mSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    mRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);

    // register listeners
    mSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
    mRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.login:
            new AttemptLogin().execute();
            break;
        case R.id.register:
            Intent i = new Intent(this, Register.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        int success;
        String username = user.getText().toString();
        String password = pass.getText().toString();
        String rememberme = check.getText().toString();

        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List params = new ArrayList();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rememberme", rememberme));


            Log.d("request!", "starting");
            // getting product details by making HTTP request
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST",
                    params);

            // check your log for json response
            Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

            // json success tag
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                // save user data
                SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(Login.this);
                Editor edit = sp.edit();
                edit.putString("username", username);
                edit.commit();

                Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, ReadComments.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(i);
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            } else {
                Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (file_url != null) {
            Toast.makeText(Login.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
}
```

ReadComments.java

```
package com.example.javi.myapplication2;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ReadComments extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private Button logout;

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// JSON parser class
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

//si lo trabajan de manera local en xxx.xxx.x.x va su ip local
// private static final String REGISTER_URL = "http://xxx.xxx.x.x:1234/cas/register.php";

//testing on Emulator:
private static final String WELCOME_URL = "http://saveds.esy.es/cas/welcome.php";

//ids
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.read_comments);

    logout=(Button)findViewById(R.id.logout);
    logout.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    new Logoutclass().execute();

}

class Logoutclass extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ReadComments.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Cerrando sesión...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Check for success tag
        int success;
        String out=logout.getText().toString();

        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List params = new ArrayList();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", out));

            Log.d("request!", "starting");

            //Posting user data to script
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    WELCOME_URL, "POST", params);

            // full json response
            Log.d("Cerrando sesión", json.toString());

            // json success element
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                Log.d("Sesión cerrada", json.toString());
                finish();
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            }else{
                Log.d("Fallo de cerrar sesión", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (file_url != null){
            Toast.makeText(ReadComments.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
}
```

register.java

```
package com.example.javi.myapplication2;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Register extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
private EditText user, pass, nam, mail ;
private Button  mRegister;

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// JSON parser class
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

//si lo trabajan de manera local en xxx.xxx.x.x va su ip local
// private static final String REGISTER_URL = "http://xxx.xxx.x.x:1234/cas/register.php";

//testing on Emulator:
private static final String REGISTER_URL = "http://saveds.esy.es/cas/register.php";

//ids
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);

    user = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
    pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    nam = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
    mail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);


    mRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.register);
    mRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    new CreateUser().execute();

}

class CreateUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating User...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Check for success tag
        int success;
        String email=mail.getText().toString();
        String name = nam.getText().toString();
        String username = user.getText().toString();
        String password = pass.getText().toString();

        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List params = new ArrayList();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));

            Log.d("request!", "starting");

            //Posting user data to script
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    REGISTER_URL, "POST", params);

            // full json response
            Log.d("Registering attempt", json.toString());

            // json success element
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                Log.d("User Created!", json.toString());
                finish();
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            }else{
                Log.d("Registering Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (file_url != null){
            Toast.makeText(Register.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Do I have to put the PHP code?

The error:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPw22.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5g8J.png)

Comment: Can you post the complete error trace?

Comment: @AlokGupta what is the error trace?

Comment: I mean the error logs that you are getting when you try to log in.

Comment: When I try to run it in my phone, and I login with a validate username the app close down @AlokGupta

Comment: Can you try it in emulator in debug mode and post the error messages that you are getting?

Comment: I edited it and there is the error

Comment: remove pDialog and debug again, see what error is throw

Answer (score 0):

Hey Pepe without seeing error whatever you got will make us complex to give you solution.

apart from that you can change your code like below

```
String data = URLEncoder.encode("user_email", "UTF-8")
            + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user_email, "UTF-8");

       data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("user_password", "UTF-8") + "="
            + URLEncoder.encode(user_password, "UTF-8");


    value = data;

        URL url;
        String response = "";
        try {
            url = new URL("Provide your URL here...");

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);


            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            //writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));
            writer.write(value);

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                String line;
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    response += line;
                    System.out.println(response);
                }
            } else {
                response = "";

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Enjoy, Happy coding....

Comment: @PepePepe, Plz call  Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, ReadComments.class);
                finish(); in postExecute method..

Comment: In Login.java first. and tell me , are getting login successful or not.

Comment: Nope, I think tha the error is here protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
           int success;
           String username = user.getText().toString();
           String password = pass.getText().toString();
           String rememberme = check.getText().toString();

           try {

                List params = new ArrayList();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rememberme", rememberme));

Comment: @PepePepe, I have given you code above. Please give it a try. If it will not work then we will solve it   anyhow.

Comment: where do I put it?, sorry i'm jus a rookie on this @Laxmeena

Comment: In your JSONParser.java

Answer (score 0):

When you get this error, it means your window is leaking the progress dialog.

Try this

```
class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    ProgressDialog pDialog; // add your pDialog here
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this, "Attempting to login",null);

    }
```

You should not add the `Intent` in `doInBackground`, instead put them in `onPostExecute`.  Read this [article](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-login-example-using-php-mysql-and-volley/) for logIn and logOut example.